# "Raw" content type support in Spring Android for custom object serialized to xml in PUT

Tags: android, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have a situation, I am using spring andorid apis to do PUT operation. The service(back end) expects xml represenatation of a custom object. And the Content-Type as "Raw". I am using SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter() to serialize the custom object to xml and setting the content type as "Raw". But this is failing and throws following exception,

"org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.test.myClass]".

The custom object class is as given below,

```
@Root
public class MyClass
 {
  @Element
  private long id_;
  @Element
  private String info_;
  @Element
  private long token_;

 public long getId() {
  return id_;
  }
  public String getInfo() {
   return info_;
  }
  public long getToken() {
   return token_;
  }
  public void setId(long id_) {
   this.id_ = id_;
  }
  public void setInfo(String info_) {
   this.info_ = info_;
  }
  public void setToken(long token_) {
   this.token_ = token_;
  }
}
```

The code that requests PUT operation is as below,

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter());
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application","Raw"));
HttpEntity<MyClass> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MyClass>(myClass, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url,
     HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, String.class);

HttpStatus status = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
```

this throws exception during the call to exchange of restTemplate.
How to resolve this, any suggestions? Is Raw type supprted by Spring Android?

Comment: Did yo resolve this issue? I also had same problem. please post the answer if it is resolved.

Comment: Yes. This issue was resolved. I had to use a custom message converter for this. Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695358/rest-template-spring-android-put-with-raw-content-type

Comment: I'll have a look that question.  If you have time can you have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553432/put-request-from-android-using-spring-resttemplate   and if possible can you answer it?

Comment: I have given my inputs to your question. Please check that.